# Which aws region was the first aws region?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In other words, where was the pioneering data center located?

The reason I'm asking is, I feel the latest firmware updates
are rolled out to a main data center before rolling out to others.

So by being on that region, we can get the latest and the greatest aws features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first region was `us-east-1` in Virginia. Anecdotally, `us-east-1` seems to have the newest features first. It is also the largest region in terms of most availability zones and broadest availability of resource types. It also seems to have outages and downtime more than other regions. However, there is sparse details on these points and I do not have a source to substantiate the claims, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Ben, Could you provide a source for "AWS recommends us-west-2"?  I couldn't find that in a few simple Google searches.

Comment: Ahh, that information is out of date. I don't think AWS recommends any region officially. Will amend the answer. Personally, I'd use us-east-2 or us-west-2. I'd never use us-east-1 if I could help it.

Answer (score 1):

The first AWS region is `us-east-1` (North Virginia). Check the AWS Global Infrastructure [here](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/).

> The reason I'm asking is, I feel the latest firmware updates are rolled out to a main data center before rolling out to others.

Most of features was launched in `us-east-1` (North Virginia) and `us-west-2` (Oregon). But, `us-east-1` not always get the new feature first. The full table of AWS region feature can be found [here](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/).

If you notice, `us-east-1` doesn't have AWS Data Pipeline yet. Some of preview features (like AWS Device Farm and AWS Elastic File Storage) are available in  `us-west-2`. It depens on the custumers need. I think the `us-west-2` is the default AWS region right now.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is still valid; looking at the linked table today, us-east-1 is the leader in features.

Comment: Yup, `us-east-1` is the leader in features. But, AWS Elastic File System preview is only in `us-west-2` at this moment.